# laravel pagination , show data when click on next page

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-8

So I'm new to laravel and I want to know how to make pagination work, in my controller I have this in the index

```
$users = Villa::with('City','Seller', 'Payment')->simplePaginate(3);
```

and for the blade, pagination nav

```
     <nav class="mt-4 " aria-label="..." >
          <ul class="pagination pagination-lg">
            <li class="page-item active" aria-current="page" >
              <span class="page-link">1</span>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="">2</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="">3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
```

the goal is when I click on the  (next page) I want it to route me to the rest of the data

what shall I do next ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put this `{{ $users->links() }}` where you want to show your pagination. It will work automatically.

Comment: Thank u, it worked, but how can I style it?

Comment: Read the docs for customize. [Customizing The Pagination View](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view)

Answer (score 0):

add this line at the bottom of your data :

```
{{ $users->links }}
```